# Google maps api v3 Marker is added but the map is not zooming

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Somedays ago , i was having this problem of not knowing how to get data from php with ajx and json, which i solved on myself, here is the link of my complete code

[How to get Coordinates from database on server, on checkbox checked and show on googlemaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834515/how-to-get-coordinates-from-database-on-server-on-checkbox-checked-and-show-on)

this is the client side code which gets coordinates through ajax request and add a marker on google maps when checkbox is checked, and removes it when un_checked.

**code**

```
function get_coordinates(checkbox){
    var v_id=checkbox.id;
    if(checkbox.checked){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST", "fetch_coordinates.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                var lat=data.loc.lat;
                var lon=data.loc.lon;
                addmarker(lat,lon,v_id);
            }
        }
         hr.send("id="+v_id);   
    } else{
        var mark = markers[v_id]; // find the marker by given id
        mark.setMap(null);
        delete markers[v_id];
    }    
}
function addmarker(lat,lon,v_id){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: v_id,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 8,    //not working
        map: map,
        title: 'Vehicle No: '+v_id
    });
    markers[v_id] = marker;

}
```

Now when i add a marker, i set my zoom level to 8, but the map doesnot zoom, i dont know why but it stands still, just adds a marker , but is not zooming. whay is that?

Answer (score 0):

A marker doesn't have a `zoom`-property, adding this property will have no effect.

You must set the properties for the map:

```
map.setOptions({center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),zoom:8});
```

Comment: ok, but my next step will be adding multiple markers, you are setting center to one marker, i dont want to do it, i want to center it on all the markers, how to do that?

Comment: by the way, thanks for the anwer, it has worked for now, just tell me how to focus all the markers in a map?

Comment: @user3493077 What do you mean by focusing all markers? Do you want to set center of the map to the center of all markers? If so, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520810/zoom-and-center-a-google-map-according-to-its-markers-javascript-api-v3